# user number and group number do not match in linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I'm having issue with my username, permissions etc. I just checked my password file and noticed my user number / group numbers don't match, they increment by one. is that normal? if not how do i fix? What are the ramifications of each? I'm scared everything will break

```
user1:x:501:502::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:502:503::/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:503:504::/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group number need not match the user number. Therefore there is nothing to fix.